# What is the most appropriate size for Training set Images for Handwriting Recognition

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, image-recognition, training-data

I'm developing an offline handwriting recognition application using neural networks(Feed forward back propagation method). I'm confused about the normalized size of the training set images of the isolated characters. Currently i'm thinking of 32*32 pixels.
Can please help me with this and are there any specific considerations to this matter.
thank you!!

Comment: To estimate an ANN solution quality, I'd use my own (biological) neural network directly, i.e. draw that image in the hypothesised resolution and feel if it's easy or difficult to recognise visually. Another thought: square proportions might be suboptimal for most letters, especially handwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more popular datasets is the [MNIST Handwritten Digits](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html) set, which contains handwritten digits. This is a version for [Matlab](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/data.html), and [Sci-kit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) has a [python machine-learning demo](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html) with it.

You will find loads of scientific papers using it as a benchmark.